# Twitter getting auth token with Javascript

Tags: javascript, twitter, authorization, fetch, twitter-oauth

When I sending POST request to the `https://api.twitter.com/oauth2/token` to receive access token from twitter, most of web browsers sending preflight `OPTIONS` request to that endpoint which is not supported by twitter and returns 400 Bad Request. So web browser will not send main request while OPTIONS request is failing. How can I solve it? Or making requests only from server is only one way?

Answer (score 0):

This request requires Application Only Authentication https://dev.twitter.com/oauth/application-only. It is meant to be a server-to-server request because it requires Twitter Application's  secret key to be sent in `Authorization` HTTP header. Technically, any HTTP client supporting *HTTP Basic Authorization* (including browser) can send that request correctly but it must have access to you App's secret key, which is not advisable.